# How To notify WCF when IIS restarted

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have WCF, my app connect via net.TCP to this WCF.
Is there a way to notify when WCF about to destroy or IIS restart?
I have callback:ServerGoingDown, and want to call it when WCF about to destroy or IIS restart/Stop.

Comment: I doubt this will be possible, but I don't know exactly. But why would you want to do so? Maybe there are alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

WCF is built on top of ASP.NET so you should be able to add a `Global.asax` file to your project and call your cleanup methods from the global `Application_OnStop` event.